# Special form for Gaussian hypergeometric function with a=1 and z=-1

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, hypergeometric-function

I have a combinatoric problem where I ran into the term

$$
(a-1)_{[k]}\ {}_2F_1(1, a, a-k, -1)
$$

where the $(a-1)_{[k]}$ indicates the falling factorial

After playing around with it and building up a relation to the generating function of [A119258](https://oeis.org/A119258) I find that

$$
(a-1)_{[k]}\ {}_2F_1(1, a, a-k, -1) = 
     \frac{k!}{2^{(k+1)}} \frac{d^a}{d x^a} \left(\frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-2x)^k}\right)_{x=0}
$$

and from this I can potentially extract a recursion to build up with or something similar, but it feels like this should have a cleaner expression (probably as some kind ratio of falling factorials in $k$) given the very specific form of the hypergeometric function provided there

Is there a nicer way to express this?

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{d}{d^a}$?

Comment: @Gary my bad just regular $a$-th derivative

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is pretty simple, by looking at first differences we can find that

$$
\frac{d^a}{d x^a} \left(\frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-2x)^k}\right)_{x=0} = \sum_{n=0}^{a} {n \choose k} 2^{(n-k)}
$$

and so we get

$$
(a-1)_{[k]}\ {}_2F_1(1, a, a-k, -1) = \sum_{n=0}^{a} (n)_{[k]} 2^{(n-2k-1)}
$$

although I'd still be much happier to have this expressed as some kind of series in $a$ instead